# What is default shell for terminal?

Tags: command-line

Let's say, I opened a terminal and entered / executed  some shell commands.

But I didn't invoke explicitly Bash or any other shell.

What shell was used by default?

Answer (score 71):

The one specified on your line in `/etc/passwd` (it is a `:` separated line and the shell is the final one).

For example mine:

```
chris:x:1000:1000:Chris,,,:/home/chris:/bin/bash
```

Here it is `/bin/bash` (the Ubuntu default)

You can also use `chsh`:

```
$ chsh
Password: 
Changing the login shell for chris
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
        Login Shell [/bin/bash]:
```

This is telling me my shell is `/bin/bash` and letting me change it.

Finally, `echo $SHELL` will do the same:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

Comment: if it's bash, why is it sometimes invoked explicitly like       sudo bash -c "netstat -an | grep LISTEN | grep -v ^unix" ??

Comment: I think that's a bad command personally - none of that even requires root. If it *did*, it would be better written as `sudo netstat -an | grep LISTEN | grep -v ^unix`. I see no reason to enclose that in a bash subshell.

Comment: @DrStrangeLove: If more than one command in the pipe needed root permissions, then `sudo bash -c "..."` would ensure that the entire pipe is executed by root.

Comment: If you don't know which commands require root (and why), you shouldn't run them. Otherwise, why trust any command/program/script any more than is required. If you can't `commandA | sudo commandB | commandC`, you could do a `sudo id` first (runs the `id` command as `root`, but also acquires a "**use sudo without password prompt**" token that lasts for (default) 15 minutes.

Comment: Duh! `sudo -v` refreshes the token without all the effort of running `id`.

Comment: If you use `chsh` then **you must log out and log back in** to see this change.

Comment: You can quickly test if everything works by switching to TTY1-7 user Ctrl+Alt+F1

Answer (score 26):

typing the following will display what shell the terminal opened with:

```
echo $SHELL
```

However, to find out what shell you are currently in (you may have changed it) type

```
ps -p $$
```

e.g. you will see that the shell is *bash* in the example output

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 3500 pts/0    00:00:01 bash
```

Another method is to use

```
echo $0
```

this will simply return the name of the current shell.

Comment: +1 for simplicity `echo $0`

Comment: Great answer! Thanks, for some reason echo $SHELL did not work (always used that one) and your two alternatives worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

GNU Bash is the shell used by default in terminals on Ubuntu.
However when scripts are executed on system boot then dash is used, as it is dash that is  /bin/sh.

This is defined in the $SHELL environmental variable. You can check by typing `echo $SHELL` in the terminal.

Answer (score 6):

By default it's bash:

```
env | grep ^SHELL=
```

In most cases will produce

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

Comment: Not necessarily. If you create a new user with `useradd`, it defaults to `sh`. `$ useradd -D|grep SHELL` `SHELL=/bin/sh`.

Comment: +1, because although the selected answer requires less typing, it's always nice to have more than one way to do something.

Answer (score 4):

To get file path of current shell executable one can use

```
readlink -f /proc/$$/exe
```

Some possible outputs are:

- `/bin/bash`
- `/usr/bin/bash`
- `/usr/bin/zsh`
- `/home/victor/.linuxbrew/Cellar/zsh/5.2/bin/zsh`