# Are there any options of bash with which it is invoked?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I [find](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87853/what-is-default-shell-for-terminal) that the default shell that I use when I start Terminal (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) is `/bin/bash`.

And running the built-in command [`type`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-type) on [`bash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) as:

```
type -p bash
```

returns the result as:

```
/bin/bash
```

Suggesting the same executable is run when I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or say `bash`.

This shell is the same as an invocation of the command [`bash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) with some of its options passed to it right? If yes, what are these options?

As an example, perhaps the `-i` option gets passed so as to make the bash shell interactive?

*PS: Maybe [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59495/difference-between-commands-in-bash-script-and-commands-in-terminal) is related too, but I cannot seem to piece together all the pieces here.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually, no, the terminal does not pass any options to `bash`. `bash` does, however, assume a set of default options depending on how it was invoked. From [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/bash.1), section `INVOCATION`:

```
An interactive shell is one started without  non-option  arguments  and
without the -c option whose standard input and error are both connected
to terminals (as determined by isatty(3)), or one started with  the  -i
option.   PS1 is set and $- includes i if bash is interactive, allowing
a shell script or a startup file to test this state.
```

An interactive shell further activates other options.
Further some defaults apply based on the invocation name (`sh` vs `bash`). Reading on (section on `set`):

```
-h      Remember  the location of commands as they are looked up
        for execution.  This is enabled by default.
-m      Monitor mode.  Job control is enabled.  This  option  is
        on  by  default  for  interactive shells on systems that
        support it (see JOB CONTROL above)
-B      The  shell performs brace expansion (see Brace Expansion
        above).  This is on by default.
-H      Enable !  style history substitution.  This option is on
        by default when the shell is interactive.
```

Combined, simply invoking `bash` on a terminal will enable these options.

You can confirm this by checking the value of the `$-` special variable:

```
$ echo $-
himBH
```

An additional option that maybe set is if your terminal is set to start login shells. In that case `-l` is explicitly passed by the terminal as an option.

Comment: So when I say Ctrl+Alt+T I start the [gnome terminal emulator](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html) which then launches my default shell (here, bash) only with the options which I see when I say `echo $-`?
Also, what exactly is `$-`? Links to some kind of documentation, article etc will be appreciated.

Comment: @Slothworks `$-` is a variable which contains the current set of options (search for `$-` in the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/bash.1)). Technically, GNOME Terminal doesn't launch your shell with any options at all. But the state in which it starts (connected to a terminal, not processing a file or executing a command) makes `bash` assume a set of default options - the one listed above. For example, if you open a terminal and run `bash` manually, it would also have these options, even though you did not use any options.

Comment: But if I were to say `bash <some script>` it could have a different set of parameters? Like you said, because of the way it was invoked. Is that right?

Comment: @Slothworks yes. It's likely it will only have `hB`. And ignore my previous comment. I meant to say: compare with the output of `bash -c 'echo $-'`

Comment: Ah yes. Running `bash -c 'echo $-'` says `hBc` which is lot more enlightening. Also, on a side note (probably this is best asked as a separate question too) , why is it that a script that does _not_ have execute permissions gets executed when run as `bash <script>`? A brief [answer is present here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/100804/85507), but some more background and a little more elaboration would be nice.

Comment: @Slothworks well, technically the script *isn't* being executed, `bash` is. The system calls involved (see `man 3 exec`) care about the permissions and type of the file being executed (`bash` when you do `bash foo`, `./foo` when you do `./foo`), and not what the arguments are. It's `bash` who will worry about whether the arguments are valid or not.

Comment: All the active options are stored in $SHELLOPTS (set-builtin-options) and $BASHOPTS (shopt-builtin-options). There are a few more than mentioned above...some are manually beeing set in ~/.bashrc, the others are active by default. 'checkwinsize' can be deleted in ~/.bahrc since it is active by default...execute 'help set' & 'help shopt' to check their meanings.