# The i-flag in $-

Tags: command-line, bash

```
echo $-
himBH
```

By default, the active flags in the set-builtin are: `himBH`
Executing `help set` doesn't show an explanation for the i-flag.

What is behind the i-flag, the i-option respectively?

Comment: Also see: http://askubuntu.com/a/660854/158442

Comment: Checked, you can update your answer there, the active set-builtin-options are in $SHELLOPTS and the active shopt-builtin-options are in $BASHOPTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man bash`:

```
-i        If the -i option is present, the shell is interactive.
```