# Remove Zsh from Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-uninstall, zsh

I installed zsh, but I realized I miss the basic/default terminal look. How can I get back to the default shell?

Comment: How did you install zsh ? `sudo apt-get purge zsh`

Comment: someone recommended me this shell, but didn't like it. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you need to configure it for sure. I use these 2 files http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/zshrc and http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/envrc (save them as ~/.zshrc and ~/.envrc )

Answer (score 38):

You can remove it completely with the following command.

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove zsh
```

If `zsh` was your default shell (see [How to check which shell am I using?](https://askubuntu.com/q/590899/283843) and [What is default shell for terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/q/87853/283843)), **Do Not forget to change it to any other shell before purging**, e.g. to `bash` like this with `root` access.

```
chsh -s /bin/bash YOUR_USERNAME
```

Or below with your login user.

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

Comment: FYI, I've had to logout/login for the `chsh` change to be visible

Comment: Would add a comment to arshin's answer but I cant: sudo apt-get --purge remove zsh zsh-* Do not forget about removing `zsh-*`! if you changed folders like `/usr/share/zsh` then reinstalling zsh without reinstalling zsh-commons will end up with a broken installation!

Comment: @ArnaudP Thank you from my heart, I've wasted lots of time and I couldn't know what was I missing, I thought of restarting the PC but I totally ignored this out of laziness, thank you

Comment: If you like me purge zsh without set other default shell, you need to copy content from `.bashrc.save` to `.bashrc` with some editor